# Is a "logged_in" session flag secure enough?

Tags: php, session-management

Is the code below enough to secure a login area?

```
<?php

if ($_SESSION['logged_in']) {
    // show content for logged-in users
}
```

Note: `$_SESSION['logged_in']` is just a boolean value `true` after validating username/pass.

Assuming you have these bases covered:

- SSL
- strong passwords
- session id regeneration
- http only
- session fingerprint

What other ways can an attacker defeat a simple `if ($_SESSION['logged_in'])` flag?

Comment: The code might be vulnerable to Session Fixation and Session Hijacking  have a look at this http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html

Comment: See also [Can Someone Fake A PHP Session Variable](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184696/can-someone-fake-a-php-session-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `if ($_SESSION['logged_in'])`

This can be secure. There is no straightforward way for an attacker to modify `$_SESSION` or the variables within. The only way it becomes `true` is when your web application sets it to `true`.